# Как создать регистрацию и авторизацию + пользователя на сайте?

Tags: php, html

Помогите мне с регистрацией и авторизацией на сайте, чтоб было все понятно, а то в Интернете один шлак.

**Обновление**

Мне непонятно, как написать на сайте html регистрацию и авторизацию, то есть в Интернете даются исходники, они все на php, к примеру, а html формы нету.

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно? Это очень обширная тема. На каком этапе вы находитесь? Какой фреймворк вы используете?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Это настолько замятая тема, что на форуме есть описание, наверное, на 20 языках как ее сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет никакой html регистрации. Формы для регистрации/авторизации ничем не отличаются от любых других форм. Например, [Форма регистрации](http://htmlbook.ru/practical/forma-registratsii) от [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/)

Почитайте весь этот "шлак" в интернете, определитесь с вопросами или претензиями и озвучьте их.

Answer (score 0):

Почитай вот эту статью думаю она поможет тебе разобраться. http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=37&id=358

Comment: Ну почему же, бекэнд не сошелся клином на PHP. Но в целом для ТС это можно сказать и так =)

Comment: В любом случае нужны сессии или куки, но на HTML их явно не создать. Плюс нужна база клиентов, иначе смысла в такой регистрации нет вовсе.

Answer (score 0):

Если описать совсем просто, то у нас есть

```
1) форма регистрации -> данные отправляются в БД -> Создаем пользователя
2) форма авторизации -> проверка наличия пользователя в БД -> получения некоторого доступа которого нет у обычных пользователь.
```

(предполагаем что все данные корректные) 
Схему можно улучшать/усложнять кучей разных вариантов, в зависимости от ваших пожеланий.